# Pygame triangle collision detection

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I'm trying to do a Triangle collision detection for my game in Pygame.
I succesfully did the collision detection for all my rectangles via the

```
rect.collidelist(rectlist)
```

But now that I have implemented the Poligons (or Triangles more precisely), I can't do any good collisions. The collisions of the Triangles are squares, so I don't know what to do now..

Comment: You've moved from the trivial world of orthogonality to the much more complex world of polygon intersections.  Is the world's granularity sufficient that you can guarantee that first contact will be at a vertex?  That's an easier problem to solve, noting whether a given point is within a given triangle.  If it's possible for a vertex to move through a triangle and out the other side (impaling) before you check, this won't work.

Comment: If you *do* have to go to full overlap detection, you might check out Luke Simonson's addition to the C++ BOOST library.  It works on generalized polygons, including cross-overs and concavities, and it's *fast*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically 2D collisions are implemented as squares in most games development frameworks. They are called "collision boxes" or "hit boxes". You could install a PyGame extension such as Pylygon to handle polygon collisions, or alternatively there is a much simpler solution:

Use multiple collision boxes on your triangle object, several small squares could map the collision detection fairly closely to the actual visual's profile. Of course this isn't going to be "pixel perfect" but it typically works pretty well, of course if you need very accurate collisions this way wouldn't suit it.

Here's a picture to illustrate what I mean by that:

[image: Triangle (Black) Collision boxes (red)]

Comment: Thanks very much bro !

Comment: No problem, I remember I had a similar problem making my first game

Answer (score 1):

So, if you want to make a triangle collision, you can use this

**Require for your triangle to calculate collision:**

- 3 points's position
- Area of the triangle

**How to calculate the area**

```
self.area = abs((self.points[1][0] - self.points[0][0]) * (self.points[2][1] - self.points[0][1]) - (self.points[2][0] - self.points[0][0]) * (self.points[1][1] - self.points[0][1]))
```

Note: this is not really the triangle, it just save a bit of time by not dividing by 2

**How to do the collision**

```
def collision(self, pos):
    area1 = abs((self.points[0][0] - pos[0]) * (self.points[1][1] - pos[1]) - (self.points[1][0] - pos[0]) * (self.points[0][1] - pos[1]))
    area2 = abs((self.points[1][0] - pos[0]) * (self.points[2][1] - pos[1]) - (self.points[2][0] - pos[0]) * (self.points[1][1] - pos[1]))
    area3 = abs((self.points[2][0] - pos[0]) * (self.points[0][1] - pos[1]) - (self.points[0][0] - pos[0]) * (self.points[2][1] - pos[1]))
    areatotal = (area1 + area2 + area3) / 2
    if areatotal == self.area:
        return True
```

So yeah, this's the tip, if you want to apply more kinds of stuff, check this:

http://www.jeffreythompson.org/collision-detection/tri-point.php

This also has the explanation so you can get to see it, I'm not very good at explaining